# Align TextView to vertical center of ImageView despite the text size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView and I want it to be followed by a TextView that will always align to it's vertical center despite of the number of lines of text.

Here's what i'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSZCr.jpg

Since I haven't found anything related to align in vertical center the only property that the text has regarding the alignment is toRightOf the ImageView.

Can someone help me on this matter?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `TableLayout` and give gravity to the `TextView` as center

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/eimaget_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/your_image"
            />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textt_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="text is here"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
```

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks, it worked nice, I just changed the android:gravity from center to center_vertical to keep it starting from the left

Comment: Actually i'm having a problem with texts longer than 1 line, please take a look matte. http://i.imgur.com/kYMPZ2F.jpg See how the text box is bypassing the border of the screen? How can I solve that?

Comment: I worked it out but now I'm getting another issue :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727908/textview-inside-tablerox-getting-cropped-any-fixes

Answer (score 8):

Instead of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`, you can use a compound drawable, which is basically a `View` that will mix both. In this `View`, you can specify the `gravity` and where the image will be located :

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/your_id"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/your_image"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/text" />
```

Answer (score 3):

set the gravity of your layout in which your image and text is present..you can also set the gravity of the textview to be center vertical or center horizontal or center