# TextView inside TableRox getting cropped - Any fixes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having this issue where my TextView inside a TableRow is getting the bottom of the second line cropped.

The only way to solve this that I found was to add margins to the FAV image on the left but it just ruined the rest of the design. Can someone explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here's the code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/link_title_favicon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="6dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
                    android:id="@+id/expandable_toggle_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/favicon_example2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/linkTitle0001"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:text="@string/link_title_001"
                    android:textColor="#777777"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkDesc0001"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/link_title_favicon"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/link_desc_001"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/labelSource0001"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linkDesc0001"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/card_label" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/labelSource0001"
        android:background="@drawable/expmenu_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!--
            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_preview_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickPreview"
            android:src="@drawable/link_preview_icon"
            android:src="@drawable/link_preview_icon" />
        -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_forward_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/link_forward_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_share_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/link_share_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_info_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/link_info_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_devices_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/link_devices_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_copyurl_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/link_copyurl_icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/link_delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/link_delete_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the bg code in case it's needed:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

            <solid android:color="#aaaaaa" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding android:bottom="6dp"
                android:left="6dp"
                android:right="6dp"
                android:top="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here's an image of my issue:
[image: Cropped Text]

Comment: Where is TableLayout in your xml?

Comment: I removed it to make it work like a linear layout, with the tablerow this happens to the text box for some reason http://i.imgur.com/kYMPZ2F.jpg

Comment: Firstly TableRow is used with the TableLayout and this problem will get solved when you give weight to the textview as 1.I've already solved this problem in my last answer

Comment: Alright, will do that, but I had the tablelayout befofe and the text was still cropped =/

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Replace the TableLayout with a LinearLayout:

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/link_title_favicon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView
                    android:id="@+id/expandable_toggle_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/favicon_example2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/linkTitle0001"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:text="@string/link_title_001"
                    android:textColor="#777777"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```